# Pass a member function as argument error: "reference to non-static member function must be called"

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and would like to know how can a member function of a class be passed to another function which takes a function pointer as a parameter. For the code I tried, I get the error of "reference to non-static member function must be called".

Edit: Making the function static would solve the issue but then I would not be able to access the variables defined in the class.

```
file.cpp:

#include "fooHdr.h"
class bar {
    void clbck() 
    {
       // Do something 
    }
    void init()
    {
        foo(clbck()); 
    }
};
```

```
fooHdr.h:
void foo(void (*hndlr)());
```

```
fooHdr.c
void foo(void (*hndlr)()) { };
```

Comment: The return type of `clbck()` is `void` so you can't use it as a parameter anywhere. You probably meant to write `foo(clbck);`, but that's a class member function, it need's to be declared as `static` class member function to get that working.

Comment: Also note that (pointers to) member functions are *not* the same a (pointers to) non-member functions.

Comment: And all of this should be in any [decent text-book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) or class.

Answer (score 1):

Member function pointers are different from normal function pointers. A normal function pointer looks like this:

```cpp
void foo() {}

void (*Func)() = foo;    // Function pointer.
```

And a member function pointer looks like this:

```cpp
class MemberTest {
public:
    void foo() {}
};

void (MemberTest::*Func)() = &MemberTest::foo;  // Member function pointer. Notice the '&' operator here.

int main()
{
    MemberTest test;
    (test.*Func)();    // This is how to call member function pointers.
}
```

Accordingly, for your problem there, you need to define it as a member function pointer and not like a normal function pointer:

```cpp
void foo(void (bar::*hndlr)());
```

And when calling the `foo()` function, it must return the address of the member function:

```cpp
void init()
{
    foo(&bar::clbck); 
}
```

But still, you can't call the function from `foo()` like this, as it doesn't have the current instance of the `bar` object. So we have to make another parameter which takes the pointer to the current object:

```cpp
void foo(bar* pBar, void (bar::*hndlr)()); 
...
foo(this, &bar::clbck);
```

So now, when calling the member function from `foo()`, you can do it like this:

```
(pBar->*hndlr)();
```

Note: Add a forward declaration on top of the function `foo()` or else the compiler might complain saying that `bar` is undefined.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for correcting me. I edited it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the foo() function is a given header function that cannot be modified.

Comment: @Cherbo Then your `clbck()` needs to be marked as `static` if you want to pass it to `foo`. And also you cannot do `foo(clbck()); `, you need to do `foo(clbck);`.